# On MongoDB, how do I filter out documents where a field with an array of strings includes a certain string?

Tags: mongodb

For example, I can have documents like:

```
doc1 = {
  title: "First blog post",
  tags: ["family", "sensitive", "private"]
}

doc2 = {
  title: "Second blog post",
  tags: ["travel", "photos"]
}
```

And I would like to list all posts that *don't* contain the "private" tag (in the se above, that would return only `doc2`). I've tried doing this:

I've tried doing this:

```
db.posts.find({$not: {tags: 'private'}})
```

It returns nothing. I've tried this:

```
db.posts.find({$not: {tags: {$all: ['private']}}})
```

Nothing still.

Then I tried this:

```
db.posts.find({$where: function() { var i; for(i=0; i < this.tags.length; i++) {if (this.tags[i] == 'private'){ return false;}}; return true;}})
```

And that got me this error:

```
"$err" : "error on invocation of $where function:\nJS Error: TypeError: this.tags has no properties nofile_b:2",
        "code" : 10071
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$not` is a bit funky, use `$ne`:

```
db.posts.find({tags : {$ne : 'private'}})
```